# Why would you smooth a logical variable in a GAM?

Tags: binary-data, generalized-additive-model, smoothing

I just used the `gam.scope` function in the R-package `gam` to create possible scopes of each explanatory variable of my model to run a `step.GAM`.
My intuition was to only provide smoothed options of numeric variables. However, `gam.scope` also provides smoothed options for logical variables. As the function is smart enough to not provide a smoothed option for factor variables, I conclude that it makes sense to smooth a logical variable.
I am quite confused by this. What is the purpose of smoothing a logical variable? How can a smoothed binary variable even look like?
Most importantly: Should I also provide smoothed options for my logical variables in my model?
A minimal reproducible example:

```
data('mtcars')

mtcars <- mtcars %>%
  mutate_at(c('vs', 'am'), as.logical) %>%
  mutate_at(c('cyl', 'gear', 'carb'), as.factor)

gam::gam.scope(mtcars)
```

Output:

```
$cyl
~1 + cyl
<environment: 0x55d261857bb0>

$disp
~1 + disp + s(disp)
<environment: 0x55d261857bb0>

$hp
~1 + hp + s(hp)
<environment: 0x55d261857bb0>

$drat
~1 + drat + s(drat)
<environment: 0x55d261857bb0>

$wt
~1 + wt + s(wt)
<environment: 0x55d261857bb0>

$qsec
~1 + qsec + s(qsec)
<environment: 0x55d261857bb0>

$vs
~1 + vs + s(vs)
<environment: 0x55d261857bb0>

$am
~1 + am + s(am)
<environment: 0x55d261857bb0>

$gear
~1 + gear
<environment: 0x55d261857bb0>

$carb
~1 + carb
<environment: 0x55d261857bb0>
```

Thanks in advance!

Lena

Comment: Any method should leave binary (logical) and unordered categorical variables alone.  One exception is numerically scoring categorical variables as done with the ACE and AVAS algorithms in the R `acepack` package.